# RuntimeError passing a yaml profile to Essentia MusicExtractor

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a feature set with the `Essentia` `MusicExtractor` from a `yaml` profile as described in the documentation [here](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/essentia_python_examples.html) and [here](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/reference/std_MusicExtractor.html) via python.

My code snippet:

```
from essentia.standard import MusicExtractor

profile = "some_profile.yaml"
audio = "some_audio.mp3"

features, frames = MusicExtractor(profile=profile)(audio)
```

My `yaml` profile:

[image]

This produces the folling error:

```
RuntimeError:
  Error while configuring MusicExtractor:
  Pool: Cannot set/add/merge value to the pool under the name 'rhythm.stats'
  because that name already exists but contains a different data type than value.
```

It does not really look that i am doing something wrong.

Comment: can you post your yaml profile?

Comment: sure. i've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it this way:

- Downloaded [a sample profile from the essentia repos](https://github.com/MTG/essentia/blob/master/src/examples/profiles/easy_config.yaml) examples.
- Ran the profile.
- Commented out the conflicting lines after each run, which are just a few. Basically the `stats` and `statsMFCC` lines.

From this I could derive a working profile.